# What is the remarkable configuration of directions at 51° N?

Tags: archaeoastronomy

A [2015 document from Stanford Solar Centre](http://solar-center.stanford.edu/AO/Ancient-Observatories.pdf) informs us that Stonehenge, The Goseck Circle and Majorville Medicine Wheel are on the same latitude (51° N.)  with the Newgrange monument  slightly to the north, and explains that

> These sites lie on the exact latitude at which the midsummer sunrise
>   and sunsets are at 90° to the Moon’s northerly setting and southerly
>   rising. This particular phenomena is only possible within a band of
>   less than one degree of which Stonehenge and Goseck lies in the
>   middle-third. The sites also sit on one of two unique latitudes in the
>   world where the full Moon passes directly overhead on its maximum
>   zeniths.

which somehow I fail to understand. What  directions are meant  - by the builders, eventually,  and/or  by the authors of the document? Does this text describe an original discovery?

Comment: How can we know for sure what the builders knew and did not know when building those structures? It is typical to infer their astronomical knowledge from the kinds of astronomical events that these structures can be linked to. Hawkins's [Stonehenge Decoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archaeoastronomy_and_Stonehenge#Gerald_Hawkins.E2.80.99_work) was written in the same spirit. By the way, the link is broken.

Comment: Fixed link. The Goseck Circle  leaves little room for doubt; there is also a book "Canada's Stonehebge". I suspect that at least one  word in the quote is out of place.

Comment: I completely doubt.   I call this serendipity, both in semirandom choice of location, combined with the random luck of civilizations developing in latitudes where the continents happened to provide sustainable life.